# How to send a variable at the click of a button to Google Apps Script and paste it into Google sheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a counter and a text field on my web-site with a **Send** button. I get the values by id and write them to variables. and then to an object. But them I can't write correctly sending this object to apps script.

Help me please understand where I have errors or where I can find code examples.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<title>Counter and text field</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2> Major: <span class="counter" id="counter18">0</span></h2>
        <button class="button-plus_minus" onclick="incrementCounter(18)">+</button>
        <button class="button-plus_minus" onclick="decrementCounter(18)">-</button>

        <textarea cols="20" rows="1" class="text-field_input" type="information" name="information" id="information" autocomplete="off"
          placeholder="Write information"></textarea>

          <button onclick="Send()">Send</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        function incrementCounter(counterNumber) {
  let counter = parseInt($('#counter' + counterNumber).text());
  counter++;

  $('#counter' + counterNumber).text(counter);
}

function decrementCounter(counterNumber) {
  let counter = parseInt($('#counter' + counterNumber).text());
  counter--;

  $('#counter' + counterNumber).text(counter);
}

function Send(){
    var information = document.getElementById('information');
    var counter18value = document.getElementById('counter18');
    var data = {
        information:information,
        counter18value:counter18value
    }
    fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/exec'), { 
    method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
}
    </script>
</html>
```

I expected the variables to go to apps script, from where they are inserted into google sheet. But I couldn't do it because they don't reach apps script.

Comment: About `I expected the variables to go to apps script, from where they are inserted into google sheet. But I couldn't do it because they don't reach apps script.`, in this case, it is required to know your whole script and setting of your Web Apps. Can you provide your Google Apps Script and the values of `Execute as:` and `Who has access to the app:` of your deployed Web Apps?

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the input references themselves instead of the values.

[Mozilla Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) says

> The getElementById() method of the Document interface returns an Element

Since `information` is a textarea, you can access its value by `.value`. Regarding `counter18`, which is a text element, you can read it's content with `.innerHTML`

Try this:

```
function Send(){
    var information = document.getElementById('information').value; // Here
    var counter18value = document.getElementById('counter18').innerHTML; // Here
    var data = {
        information: information,
        counter18value: counter18value
    }

    fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/exec'), { 
    method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
}
```

Also, I'd replace `var` with `const` just for the meaning and scope, but that shouldn't affect your problem.